# Is it possible to have a ZendDeveloperTools Toolbar entry for a module, without creating a Collector?

Tags: zend-framework2, toolbar

All I want to show there is available via ViewHelpers provided by the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. I wanted to avoid the creation of a "dummy" Collector, because - as mentioned in the question, all I want to be visible on the toolbar, is available through provided view helpers.

Now I'm just pointing the Collector, to a collector that was already registered by the ZendDeveloperTools module (`ZendDeveloperTools\RequestCollector`):

```
return array(
    'zenddevelopertools' => array(
        'profiler' => array(
            'collectors' => array(
                'MyCollecor' => 'ZendDeveloperTools\RequestCollector'
            ),
        ),
        'toolbar'  => array(
            'entries' => array(
                'MyCollecor' => 'zend-developer-tools/toolbar/websafe-zf-mod-language',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

I hope that's OK.